# Quickest way to find characteristic polynomial from a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the Rational form of 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&0&4\\ \:\:\:4&1&2&0\\ \:\:\:0&4&1&2\\ \:\:\:2&0&4&1\end{pmatrix}
$$

I don't wanna the solution, instead I would like to know a quickest  way to calculate $\det (\lambda I-A)$. 
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
x-1 &-2  &0  &-4 \\ 
 -4&x-1  &-2  &0 \\ 
 0&-4  &x-1  & -2 \\ 
 -2&0  &-4  &x-1 
\end{vmatrix}
$$

here I could see the polynomial but the procedure is quite long.
https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-eigenvectors-calculator/eigenvectors%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D1%262%260%264%5C%5C%20%20%20%20%204%261%262%260%5C%5C%20%20%20%20%200%264%261%262%5C%5C%20%20%20%20%202%260%264%261%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add columns $\,2,3,4\,$ to the first one (this is a circulant matrix), and get:

$$\det(t I-A)=\begin{vmatrix}t-7&-2&0&-4\\
t-7&t-1&-2&0\\
t-7&-4&t-1&-2\\
t-7&0&-4&t-1\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{R_i-R_1}=\begin{vmatrix}t-7&-2&0&-4\\
0&t+1&-2&4\\
0&-2&t-1&2\\
0&2&-4&t+3\end{vmatrix}=$$$${}$$

$$=(t-7)\begin{vmatrix}
t+1&-2&4\\
-2&t-1&2\\
2&-4&t+3\end{vmatrix}=(t-7)\left[(t^2-1)(t+3)+24+8t+8-4t-12-8t+8\right]=$$

$$=(t-7)\left[(t^2-1)(t+3)-4t+28\right]=(t-7)\left[t^3+3t^2-5t+25\right]=$$

$$=(t-7)(t+5)(t^2-2t+5)=(t+t)(t+5)(t-(1-2i))(t-(1+2i))$$

Comment: Both answers are great! However I'll choose this one, thank you.

Comment: @ipreferpi Thanks, though I would have chosen the other one. Yet for the other one it'd be necessary to understand (or prove) the results mentioned there. For something more elementary, perhaps this answer is more suited.

Answer (score 3):

The quick way is to realise you have a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), so you can immediately write down the determinant
\begin{align*}
&\det\begin{pmatrix}
x-1 &-2  &0  &-4 \\ 
 -4&x-1  &-2  &0 \\ 
 0&-4  &x-1  & -2 \\ 
 -2&0  &-4  &x-1 
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=(x-1-2-4)(x-1-2i+4i)(x-1+2+4)(x-1+2i-4i)
\end{align*}
since the eigenspaces are $\langle(1,i^k,i^{2k},i^{3k})\rangle=\langle(1,i^k,(-1)^k,(-i)^k)\rangle$, for $k=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: "Since the eigenspaces are..." So you have to know **first** the eigenspaces?

Comment: Circulant matrices always have eigenspaces in this form, because these preserve the symmetry and are enough of them.  No calculation needed (except to show they are independent, which follows from the vandermonde determinant).

Comment: Is there any way only using determinant properties?

Comment: Yes, using the basic properties of circulant matrices it is way faster and easier...+1